# Create folders with leading zeroes in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've been using this script to create folders:

```
$i = 1
cd\
md d:\user$1
$i++
```

However it spits out folder like these...

```
d:\user1
d:\user2
d:\user3
```

What i want is two leading zeros, so that when i get to `009` it gracefully switches to a single leading zero.
Like wise at `099` it should transition to `100`.

This is what I want it to output:

```
d:\user001
d:\user010
d:\user100
```

Currently i'm inserting the zeros into the script to before the `$i`, and removing it as it jumps into the second and third digits.
Everything i have read mentions using a string to get the preceding zeros.

Is that the only way?

> **Question from:**
>   Reddit: [Get powershell to count and include the leading zeros without using a string?](http://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/20tgxa/get_powershell_to_count_and_include_the_leading/)

Comment: The answer is "No."  Folder names are by definition string values, so there really isn't any way around dealing with them as strings eventually.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use something like this:

```
0..10 | % { "user{0:000}" -f $_ } | % { New-Item -ItemType directory -Name $_ }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just replace your md command with something like:

```
md ( "d:\user" + ( "{0:D3}" -f $i ))
```

Still kinda arcane, but seems to work for me...